# Detect overlapping circles (spheres) with shadows with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-detection, watershed

I am writing a program with `OpenCV` that detects circles in the structure pictures. I'm using the **Watershed method** described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932891/detect-touching-overlapping-circles-ellipses-with-opencv-and-python).

There is a problem I faced: 3d structure photo is hardly converted into a binary picture (due to shadows and different depth), so the program can't spot circles. Here you can see my best results of processing 3d structures (2d are detected perfectly).

[image: original]

[image: binary]

[image: processed]

So, is there any way to process pictures of 3d structure and make it possible to convert it into an acceptable bin picture and process with watershed? Maybe I should use a completely different method?

My code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('spheres1.bmp')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_min = np.array((0, 0, 110), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((0, 0, 255), np.uint8)
gray = hsv[:, :, 2]
gray = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)

bw = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 13)

#then I use Watershed algorithm
```

Comment: that is an electron microscopy image, just to state the obvious. -- that *is* a tough picture to work with. no sharp edges, generally noisy, bubbles of varying size and shape, occluding each other... -- "cheap" methods won't work here. especially not anything presented in random blogs/youtube tutorials addressed to newbies. -- when in doubt, use AI. *maybe* instance segmentation could be trained to label each of these bubbles.

Comment: Actually, the main goal of my program is not the spheres detection, I am just trying to save expert's time on matching structures. How many samples you think it is required to train and test AI with this method?

Comment: can't say. dozens perhaps, depending on the network and if it's just tuned ("transfer learning") or trained from scratch (would be unreasonable).

Comment: Have you tried [Hough circles](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html)? It may be able to do better at detecting circles in the background.

Comment: Yes, that was the first i've tried. It doesn't spot them due to overlays.